# Flutter Web - Open new tab but keeping primary tab on focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
await launchUrl(
  uri,
  webOnlyWindowName: isNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self',
);
```

with _blank **launchUrl** open new tab but it changes tab focus to new tab. How can I keep tab focus into existing tab not new tab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.